# Why is the LoginPath not working? It keeps going to /Account/Login but with 404

Tags: asp.net-core-mvc, .net-6.0

I use ASP.NET Core 6 MVC, I'm trying to prevent user to bypass the login page by accessing the url directly, like for example, I put `[Authorize]` on the `SalesController`, I expect when user access directly to the `/Sales/any_actions` then they would be kicked over to the login page.

I have configured `LoginPath` to `/User/Login` but when I try to bypass the login page by accessing `/Sales/List`, it keeps going to `/Account/Login` and results in a 404 not found. Yes I understood there is no `/Account/Login` page, but why it still keeps going to `/Account/Login` although I already configured the `LoginPath` as below?

What I have missed here?

```
    builder.Services.ConfigureApplicationCookie(options =>
    {
        options.LoginPath = "/User/Login";    
        options.AccessDeniedPath = "/User/Login";
        options.LogoutPath = "/User/Logout";
        options.SlidingExpiration = true;
    });

    [HttpGet]
    [Route("/User/Login")]
    [AllowAnonymous]
    public IActionResult Login()
    {
        return View(ViewData);
    }

    [Authorize]
    public class SalesController : Controller
    {
        public IActionResult Index()
        {
            return View();
        }
    }

**Full of program.cs**

    
    builder.Services.AddCors(options =>
    {
        options.AddPolicy(name: "_myAllowSpecificOrigins",
          builder =>
          {
             builder.WithOrigins(hosts);
          });
     });

     builder.Services.AddDataProtection()
      .SetApplicationName(Xtender.Models.AppSettings.Application.Name)
      .PersistKeysToFileSystem(new 
       DirectoryInfo(Xtender.Models.AppSettings.Path.Key_Ring))
       .SetDefaultKeyLifetime(TimeSpan.FromDays(14));

       builder.Services.AddDistributedMemoryCache();


       builder.Services.AddSession(so =>
       {
          so.Cookie.Name = ".test_mycookie";
          so.Cookie.HttpOnly = true;
          so.Cookie.IsEssential = true;
        });

        builder.Services.ConfigureApplicationCookie(options =>
        {
          options.LoginPath = "/User/Login";    
          options.AccessDeniedPath = "/User/Login";
          options.LogoutPath = "/User/Logout";
          options.SlidingExpiration = true;
         });

        builder.Services.AddHttpContextAccessor();
        builder.Services.AddMemoryCache();

        builder.Services.AddAntiforgery(opts => opts.Cookie.Name = 
         "__RequestVerificationToken");
         builder.Services.AddControllersWithViews()
        .AddSessionStateTempDataProvider();

         builder.Services.AddScheduler((sender, args) =>
         {
             args.SetObserved();
         });

        builder.Services.Configure<KestrelServerOptions>(options =>
        {
          options.AllowSynchronousIO = true;
        });

        builder.Services.AddSingleton<IHttpContextAccessor, 
        HttpContextAccessor>();

        builder.Services.Configure<CookiePolicyOptions>(options =>
        {
            cookies is needed for a given request.  
            options.CheckConsentNeeded = context => true;
            options.MinimumSameSitePolicy = SameSiteMode.None;
         });
 
builder.Services.AddAuthentication(CookieAuthenticationDefaults.AuthenticationScheme).AddCookie();
builder.Services.AddMvc(option =>
{
    option.EnableEndpointRouting = false;
}).AddNewtonsoftJson();

builder.Services.AddWebSocketManager();

// Add services to the container.
builder.Services.AddControllersWithViews();

if (!builder.Environment.IsDevelopment())
{
    builder.WebHost.UseKestrel(serverOptions =>
    {
        serverOptions.ListenAnyIP(5055);
    });
}

var app = builder.Build();

// Configure the HTTP request pipeline.
if (!app.Environment.IsDevelopment())
{
    app.UseExceptionHandler("/Home/Error");
    // The default HSTS value is 30 days. You may want to change this for production scenarios, see https://aka.ms/aspnetcore-hsts.
    app.UseHsts();
}

app.UsePathBase(Xtender.Models.AppSettings.Path.Deployment);
app.UseCors(hosts);
app.UseCookiePolicy();
app.UseAuthentication();

#region Websocket

var serviceScopeFactory = ((IApplicationBuilder)app).ApplicationServices.GetRequiredService<IServiceScopeFactory>();
var serviceProvider = serviceScopeFactory.CreateScope().ServiceProvider;
var webSocketOptions = new WebSocketOptions()
{
    KeepAliveInterval = TimeSpan.FromSeconds(120)
};
webSocketOptions.AllowedOrigins.Add("*");
app.UseWebSockets(webSocketOptions);
app.MapWebSocketManager("/ws", serviceProvider.GetService<NotificationsMessageHandler>());

#endregion

app.UseHttpsRedirection();
app.UseStaticFiles();
app.UseRouting();
app.UseAuthorization();
app.UseSession();
app.MapControllerRoute(
    name: "default",
    pattern: "{controller=Home}/{action=Index}/{id?}");

app.Run();
```

[image: Page not found and goes to /Account/Login]

Comment: According to the code you have provided so far, the same problem as you did not occur. If you added [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example), it would be easier to tell. I'm not sure, at this stage.

Comment: Could you share more code of your Program.cs?

Comment: @QingGuo .. will update my question

Comment: "it keeps going to /Account/Login and results in a 404 not found" Do you have home/index view? And can you share the error page?

Comment: added an 404 image

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If you are using the ASP.NET Core Identity, you need to set the `LoginPath` property in `ConfigureApplicationCookies` after calling `AddIdentity` or `AddDefaultIdentity`.

You can click this [link](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/security/authentication/identity-configuration?view=aspnetcore-5.0#cookie-settings) to view the document.

```
services.ConfigureApplicationCookie(options =>
{
    options.LoginPath = "/User/Login";
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Remove your code

```
        builder.Services.ConfigureApplicationCookie(options =>
        {
          options.LoginPath = "/User/Login";    
          options.AccessDeniedPath = "/User/Login";
          options.LogoutPath = "/User/Logout";
          options.SlidingExpiration = true;
         });
builder.Services.AddAuthentication(CookieAuthenticationDefaults.AuthenticationScheme).AddCookie();
```

Add below

```
builder.Services.AddAuthentication(CookieAuthenticationDefaults.AuthenticationScheme)
                .AddCookie( options =>
                {
                   options.LoginPath = "/User/Login";    
                   options.AccessDeniedPath = "/User/Login";
                   options.LogoutPath = "/User/Logout";
                   options.SlidingExpiration = true;
                });
```

Comment: thank you so much!, you're really safe my time!, I have been exploring on this for 3 days!