# Redirect to login when unauthorized not working

Tags: asp.net-core, asp.net-core-6.0

Am running a .netcore 6 web application that communicates with an API, using jwt token for authenication.

I can't seem to understand why my statusCodePages are not been used instead it return a browser default page.

I did all the necessary configurations as show in the code blow

```
services.AddSession(options =>
        {
            options.Cookie.Name = "Cookie Name";
            options.IdleTimeout = TimeSpan.FromHours(5);
            options.Cookie.IsEssential = true;
            options.Cookie.HttpOnly = true;
            options.Cookie.SameSite = SameSiteMode.Strict;
        });
```

and i also did configure applicationcookie

```
services.ConfigureApplicationCookie(options =>
        {
            options.AccessDeniedPath = Globals.AuthCookies.AccessDeniedPath;
            options.LoginPath = Globals.AuthCookies.LoginPath;
        
            options.Cookie.IsEssential = true;
            options.Cookie.SameSite = SameSiteMode.Strict;
            options.Cookie.SecurePolicy = CookieSecurePolicy.Always;

        });
```

Yet it still doesn't work, i had to manually intercept all the statusErrorCodes and redirect to my customPages.

```
app.UseStatusCodePages(async context =>
{
       var response = context.httpcontext.response;
       if (response.statuscode == (int)httpstatuscode.unauthorized)
       {
          response.redirect(globals.authcookies.loginpath + "?returnUrl=" + context.HttpContext?.Request.Path.Value);
       }
       else if (response.statuscode == (int)httpstatuscode.forbidden)
       {
          response.redirect(globals.authcookies.accessdeniedpath);
       }
      else if (response.statuscode == (int)httpstatuscode.notfound)
      {

      }
 });
```

And it works but, I would love to know why the normal configureApplicationCookie approach isn't working anymore

Comment: `ConfigureApplicationCookie` must be called after calling `AddIdentity` or `AddDefaultIdentity`, otherwise it has no effect. Is your execution order correct? Refer to [this link](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/security/authentication/identity-configuration?view=aspnetcore-7.0#cookie-settings).

Comment: i did everything correct just as you mentioned

Comment: I noticed that `options.Cookie.Name` ,  `options.Cookie.HttpOnly` are set in `ConfigureApplicationCookie` in the [official document](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/security/authentication/identity-configuration?view=aspnetcore-7.0#cookie-settings), you can try it. And there is another method in [this link](https://stackoverflow.com/a/72444279/18789859). In addition, do you have [this problem](https://github.com/dotnet/aspnetcore/issues/5828)?

Comment: i had already read through every links there and tried out all those methods